# KnockoutJS - Components - Multiple instances

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this KnockoutJS Component that I need to have multiple instances of on the same page. I ran into problems that the different instances seems to share the observable properties. So if one of the textareas is updated, the others on the same page is also updated.

I have tried to set unique id's on the different textareas as a test, but that didn't solve it.

Here is my component code:

```
ko.components.register('note-editor', {
    viewModel: (params) => {
        var self = this;

        this.id = uid.new('note-editor-');
        this.title = ko.observable(params && params.title || '');
        this.titleClass = ko.observable(params && params.titleClass || '');
        this.expandTooltip = ko.observable(params && params.expandTooltip || '');
        this.numberOfCharactersLeft = ko.observable(params && params.numberOfCharactersLeft || '');
        this.limitCharacters = ko.observable(params && params.limitCharacters || 1000);

        this.showNote = params.showNote;
        this.notes = params.notes;
        this.showIcon = ko.computed(() => {
            return self.notes() != undefined && self.notes() != '';
        });
        this.notesCount = ko.computed(() => {
            var value = self.notes(),
                charLimit = self.limitCharacters();

            if (value) {
                var characters = charLimit - value.length;

                if (characters < 0) {
                    return 0;
                }

                return characters;
            }

            return charLimit;
        });
    },
    template: '<div data-bind="text: title, attr: { class: titleClass }"></div>'
    + '<div tabindex="1" data-bind="toggleButton: showNote, attr: { title: expandTooltip }" class="toggleButton"></div><img data-bind="visible: showIcon" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" style="margin-bottom: -7px" />'
    + '<div class="note-counter" data-bind="visible: showNote, style: { fontWeight: notesCount() == 0 ? \'bold\' : \'\' }">'
    + '<span data-bind="text: notesCount()" > </span><span data-bind="text: numberOfCharactersLeft"></span>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<textarea data-bind="visible: showNote, value: notes, valueUpdate: [\'input\', \'afterkeydown\'], limitCharacters: limitCharacters, attr: { id: id, name: id }" tabindex="1"></textarea>'
});
```

The viewmodel and the template will be in external files when finished.

If I place 3-4 instances of the component above it seems that it's only the last instance that "works".

Tried to google this problem for a couple of hours, but no success :(

Hope someone can show me the right approach!

Comment: What `params` are you passing? E.g.: in your viewModel constructor you're using `this.notes = params.notes`. This means that if `params.notes` is an observable that is passed to multiple components, it'll be a shared property.

Comment: The markup for the different instances look like this (it's different observables that is passed to notes / showNote). http://pastebin.com/nvCxWPPb

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's wrong, but this is what I was referring to: https://jsfiddle.net/t76722qu/ Note that `text` is initialized _inside_ the constructor and therefore _unique_ to each component _instance_. `shared` is passed via `params` and therefore shared by _all_ components. (try clicking `true`/`false` to see it change for all components)

Comment: Yes I understand the concept, but my **notes** property shouldn't be shared. Because 2 different observables is passed to it through params. But now when I write about I'm starting to understand the issue better. Because all the different observables is passed to the component through params it's **marked** as shared.

Comment: Would it in some way be possible to give the component observable properties as parameter and not have them shared?

Comment: But there must be something else that is wrong. Because if I try to change them to observables that is initialized within the constructor it behaves in them same way. Both of the textareas is updated with the same value as soon as I write in one of them? http://pastebin.com/nh8Zfqec

Comment: Yeah it's probably something else. It's hard for me to tell from just this snippet. Can you reproduce it in a fiddle? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Strange, must be something within our application that is interfering with the component / properties / variables. Because when I did this on jsFiddle it works as expected ;) https://jsfiddle.net/gzmamnfg/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after numerous hours I found the solution. I had to use the createViewModel factory pattern. If not used then the viewmodel will be used as a singleton instance and that was my problem.

I really don't like that the singleton pattern is default. I could implement the singleton pattern if needed myself with the createViewModel factory pattern.

Anyway, it's solved so I thought I should post my solution here for any other looking for answers :)

```
function noteViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = uid.new('note-editor-');
    self.title = ko.observable(params && params.title || '');
    self.titleClass = ko.observable(params && params.titleClass || '');
    self.expandTooltip = ko.observable(params && params.expandTooltip || '');
    self.numberOfCharactersLeft = ko.observable(params && params.numberOfCharactersLeft || '');
    self.limitCharacters = ko.observable(params && params.limitCharacters || 1000);

    self.showNote = params.showNote;
    self.editorNotes = params.notes;

    self.showIcon = ko.computed(() => {
        return self.editorNotes() != undefined && self.editorNotes() != '';
    });

    self.notesCount = ko.computed(() => {
        var value = self.editorNotes(),
            charLimit = self.limitCharacters();

        if (value) {
            var characters = charLimit - value.length;

            if (characters < 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            return characters;
        }

        return charLimit;
    });
}

ko.components.register('note-editor', {
    viewModel: (params) => {
        createViewModel: return new noteViewModel(params);
    },
    template: '<div data-bind="text: title, attr: { class: titleClass }"></div>'
    + '<div tabindex="1" data-bind="toggleButton: showNote, attr: { title: expandTooltip }" class="toggleButton"></div><img data-bind="visible: showIcon" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=5&txt=30%C3%9730&w=20&h=20" style="margin-bottom: -7px" />'
    + '<div class="note-counter" data-bind="visible: showNote, style: { fontWeight: notesCount() == 0 ? \'bold\' : \'\' }">'
    + '<span data-bind="text: notesCount()" > </span><span data-bind="text: numberOfCharactersLeft"></span>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<textarea data-bind="visible: showNote, value: editorNotes, valueUpdate: [\'input\', \'afterkeydown\'], limitCharacters: limitCharacters, attr: { id: id, name: id }" tabindex="1"></textarea>'
});
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: any idea how to do this with external component files?